# UseState multiple initial states

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend

I'm trying to initialize a constant variable which may either be used as a string or an array of strings depending on a prop that my component is receiving.

I'm trying to initialize it as

```
const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState<string[] | string>([]);
```

I realized that this is the incorrect way as this identifies the state as `string[] | string` rather than `string[]` or `string`. How should I go about initializing it instead?

Comment: You can make a separate type and use it here. But what is the difference bw `string[] | string` and `string[]` or `string`?

Comment: Have you tried with double pipe? `||`

Comment: @TusharShahi the word 'string[] | string' gets considered as a type

Comment: @Camilo Yes, I get an `Unexpected token` error.

Comment: you can use type guards when using selectedOptions value

Comment: You might want to share an example of the properties that influence the type in the state. It's very possible that this is solvable with generics, but I need a complete sample.

Answer (score 2):

I think it does exactly what you want. See the following example:

```
const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState<string[] | string>([]);

const arrayState: string[] = selectedOptions;
```

As expected, Typescript throws the following Error:

```
Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.(2322)
```

The same happens with a string variable (just the other way around):

```
const stringState: string = selectedOptions;
```

If you've got different Child-Components, with props that expect different types, the following Snippet should be helpful.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const SelectionSet = () => {
    const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState<string[] | string>([]);


    if(Array.isArray(selectedOptions)) {
        const arrayState: string[] = selectedOptions;
        return <ComponentA arrayProp={arrayState} />
    } 
    
    
    const stringState: string = selectedOptions;
    
    return <ComponentB stringProp={stringState} />        
}
```

The variables are just there for an explanatory reason. You could also set the props direclty by using the `selectedOptions` state.

On the other hand, if you want to use the `selectedOptions`-state always on the same child component, something like the following lines might be a solution:

```
const SelectionSet = () => {
    const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState<string[] | string>([]);

    // note the negation 
    if(!Array.isArray(selectedOptions)) {
        return <ComponentC stringProp={selectedOptions} />        
    } 
    
    
    return selectedOptions.map((option, key) => {
        return <ComponentC stringProp={option} key={key} />        
    });    
}
```